# SQL, extra column with number of elements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my query with this information

```
select accounts, associated from companies
```

As Result:

```
Accounts: - Associated:
C10       -   a1
C10       -   a1
C10       -   b1
C82       -   a1
C82       -   c3
B7        -   a1
B7        -   a1
R5        -   c4
Q1        -   a1
```

I'd love to write a query to count the total of associated for each account and have this results (2 different columns):

```
Accounts: - Number:
C10       -  2
C82       -  2
B7        -  1
R5        -  1
Q1        -  1
```

Some help please? I'm sure that I can but I don't know how :S

---

*new question originally posted as an answer:*

Table:

```
Accounts: - Associated:
C10       -   a1
C10       -   a1
C10       -   b1
C82       -   a1
C82       -   c3
B7        -   a1
B7        -   a1
R5        -   c4
Q1        -   a1
```

I have to make the count based on the 2 column (associated) for have this result:

```
Accounts: - Number:
C10       -  2
C82       -  2
B7        -  1
R5        -  1
Q1        -  1
```

Comment: Same Companyid several times in the company table? Seems strange.

Comment: @jarlh it's not in the same table, I have different join in the system I just wrote the interested part otherwise the code would be very long and maybe not very clear for who read!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do a `GROUP BY` on `companyid` (or whatever your `Accounts` column is), and use `COUNT()` aggregate function

```
SELECT companyid, count(*) AS Cnt
FROM companies
GROUP BY companyid
```

---

Answer to question 2:

```
SELECT companyid, COUNT(DISTINCT Associated) AS Cnt
FROM companies
GROUP BY companyid
```

Comment: just one more thing pls, is it possible group twice in an unique query? Because I wrote my query to simplify and understand how to do but my query is much more complex :S

Comment: @Carlo1585 elaborate please.  group twice on what?

Comment: I answer my question so I can give you more details and examples ;)

Comment: @Carlo1585 don't do that, your new "question" will be deleted because it is not an answer. You should **edit** your original question to add more details.

Comment: @Carlo1585: Based on your "answer" you want a `COUNT(DISTINCT Associated)`

Comment: @dnoeth I edit my first question too, in every case I'm going to try it and let you know ;) thanks so much :D

Comment: @Carlo1585 please delete your answer, I have edited your original question to add the new info. And I have edited my answer to add the new query you need.

Comment: @ThomasG done, in any case I try the solution that dnoeth gave to me and it's working ;) thanks so much to everyone for the help :D

Comment: @dnoeth thanks so much and thanks to everyone, the solution is perfectly working :D thanks guys

Comment: @Carlo1585 Glad to help.  one more duty for you : when an answer do answer your question, you should mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: @ThomasG oh ok ;) thanks so so much :D last thing, do I need close this post? or do something or I can just leave it?!?!?!? I'm pretty new of this forum :S

Comment: @Carlo1585 _To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in._  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)